# Check if a string is equal with a variable name

Tags: python

I want to know if it is possible to compare if a string is equal with a variable name.
For example I have the following declaration:

```
S=['A']
A=[['C'],['A','c','C']]
C=[['a'],['b'],['d','D']]
D=['A','e']
M=[S,A,C,D]
temp=[]
```

and

```
temp.append(S[0])
if S[0] in M :
...
```

Therefore I need to check if a string is equal with a variable name.
Is it possible to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to know if `M` contains a reference to the same list as what `A` refers to? Python names are mere references; what if there is a `B` that refers to the same list, for example?

Comment: what is exactly your use-case for this?

Comment: I need this for left/right terminal sets at Formal Language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to derefence `A` first, using `globals()` for example:

```
if globals()[S[0]] in M:
```

However, you should *rarely* need to use this, however. Generally, you'd have such objects in a dictionary of your own, for example:

```
lists = {'A': [...], 'C': [...]}
```

and then you just test if `S[0] in lists` is True.